# Android Andengine poor texture quality

Tags: android, textures, andengine

The problem: poor texture quality in android app written with Andengine(wraps opengl), especially on gradients which appear as steps in few colours. Problem occurs on real and virtual device

Settings: default texture, fullscreen, native resolution, android 2.2.
I have tried to enforce PixelFromat with:

```
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Haven't made any difference.

Commenting line: 
`GLHelper.disableDither(pGL);` helped a little with textures, but made particles look bad, so a guess it is not the source of problem.

Example loading code:

```
public static void loadResources(StreamgameActivity game) {
    magnetTexture = new BitmapTextureAtlas(512, 512, TextureOptions.BILINEAR);
    magnetTextureRegion = BitmapTextureAtlasTextureRegionFactory
       .createFromAsset(magnetTexture, game,"bateria128CMatte_none.png", 0, 0);
    game.getEngine().getTextureManager().loadTexture(magnetTexture);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Andengine seems to use be default 16bit rendering mode. To change that I have done:

```
this.mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
mRenderSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8,8,8,8,0,0);//!!
mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine);
mRenderSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);//!!
```

in `onSetContentView` method.

Comment: Do you know how to solve this in the new andengine using GLES2?

Comment: Does anyone know how to change rendering mode in Live Wallpaper extension? That is, in an instance of BaseLiveWallpaperService.

Answer (score 2):

If someone is experiencing poor texture quality and banding for GLES2 here is the solution:
just override `preDraw()` of your Sprite and enable dithering like this:

```
Sprite electricityOff = new Sprite(0, 0, mElectricityOffTextureRegion, getVertexBufferObjectManager()) {
    @Override
    protected void preDraw(GLState pGLState, Camera pCamera) {
        super.preDraw(pGLState, pCamera);
        pGLState.enableDither();
    }
};
```

Key element is `pGLState.enableDither();`.
You will **not** need anything else but in case you want to ensure 32bit rendering for the surface and activity you can add:

```
@Override
protected void onSetContentView() {
    mRenderSurfaceView = new RenderSurfaceView(this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setEGLConfigChooser(8, 8, 8, 8, 24, 0);
    mRenderSurfaceView.setRenderer(mEngine, this);
    mRenderSurfaceView.getHolder().setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

    this.setContentView(mRenderSurfaceView, BaseGameActivity.createSurfaceViewLayoutParams());
}


@Override
public void onAttachedToWindow() {
    super.onAttachedToWindow();
    Window window = getWindow();
    window.setFormat(PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, fixed by enabling Dithering

```
EngineOptions options;
//..........
options.getRenderOptions().setDithering(true);
```